# How to find the value of $\frac{1}{2015!}+\sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

I have a question about simplifying the sigma notation and permutation in fraction.

Here is  the question:

How to find the value of $\frac{1}{2015!}+\sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}$ ?

My thinking is I need to find the pattern for the sigma notation here, such that:

$\sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}$ = $\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+....+\frac{2014}{2015!}$

But, the denominator is too high to simplify and also I think it will cost much time to simplify every fraction here.

I've used the calculator and found out that the answer is $1$. But, how can we arrive at this solution manually?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $\frac{k}{(k+1)!} = \frac{1}{k!} - \frac{1}{(k+1)!}$

Comment: Use @achillehui 's hint to conclude that $\sum_{k=1}^{2014} \frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{(k+1)!-1}{(k+1)!}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac1{k!}-\frac1{(k+1)!}
$$
Sum the [Telescoping Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) to get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac1{1!}-\frac1{2015!}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac1{2015!}+\sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{(k+1)!}$. So $S_1=\frac{1}{2}$, $S_2=\frac{5}{6}$, $S_3=\frac{23}{24}$ and we conjecture that $S_n=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$. By induction, since $S_{n+1}=S_n+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}$ we have $S_{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}.$